# I am tried to prestashop database error

Tags: prestashop

my site url is :- http://www.latinwaymusic.it/prestashop/

check errors :-
(1) Db->executeS() must be used only with select, show, explain or describe queries

at line 498 in file classes/db/Db.php

(2)DbCore->executeS - [line 330 - classes/shop/Shop.php] - [1 Arguments]

(3)ShopCore::initialize - [line 100 - config/config.inc.php]

(4)require - [line 27 - index.php] - [1 Arguments]

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your shop domain/url are empty, you should check your database for eg. in phpMyAdmin, serach for the `ps_shop_url` table and in `domain` and `domain_ssl` type `www.latinwaymusic.it` in `physical_uri` type `/prestashop/` and save the row.

Answer (score 0):

The query you are building is problematic. Have you updated the code yourself? 
The query looks like this:

```
SELECT s.id_shop, CONCAT(su.physical_uri, su.virtual_uri) AS uri, su.domain, su.main
FROM ps_shop_url su
LEFT JOIN ps_shop s ON (s.id_shop = su.id_shop)
WHERE (su.domain = "". pSQL($HOST)."" OR su.domain_ssl = "". pSQL($HOST)."")
    AND s.active = 1
    AND s.deleted = 0
ORDER BY LENGTH(CONCAT(su.physical_uri, su.virtual_uri)) DESC
```

In the code at line 325 in file classes/shop/Shop.php, the

```
WHERE (su.domain = "". pSQL($host)."" OR su.domain_ssl = "". pSQL($host)."")
```

should be

```
WHERE (su.domain = \''.pSQL($host).'\' OR su.domain_ssl = \''.pSQL($host).'\')
```

Your code has "" (two-times double quote) which seems to be coming from MS SQLServer SQL syntax, which will never work in PHP.

Comment: Hello inam101

Thanks for your reply .. When I added WHERE (su.domain = \''.pSQL($host).'\' OR su.domain_ssl = \''.pSQL($host).'\') then display another Parse error check this :-  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /web/htdocs/www.latinwaymusic.it/home/prestashop/classes/shop/Shop.php on line 325

Comment: You should use the following code for replacement:
WHERE (su.domain = \"".pSQL($host)."\" OR su.domain_ssl = \"".pSQL($host)."\")

Comment: Hello sir,    I have already used this code but  its not working for me.